# Visual Studio Code (Git: Bad status code: 500)

Tags: flutter, dart, github, visual-studio-code

I am trying to commit changes from my Flutter codes to my GitHub repositories but this error keeps showing up.

[image]

This is the gitlog.
I want to sync it to GitHub.
Also, how can I disconnect my local code to a repository in GitHub since this error keeps showing off?

```
    [2022-07-09T08:38:34.408Z] Log level: Info
    [2022-07-09T08:38:34.409Z] [info] Validating found git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
    [2022-07-09T08:38:34.557Z] [info] Using git 2.36.0.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
    [2022-07-09T08:38:35.008Z] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [440ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:35.627Z] > git rev-parse --git-dir --git-common-dir [603ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:35.638Z] [info] Open repository: c:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Downloads\grabbitapp-v1.0.9
    [2022-07-09T08:38:36.070Z] > git status -z -uall [413ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:36.154Z] > git fetch [506ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:36.284Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [210ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:36.518Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [230ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:36.839Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [317ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:36.840Z] > git remote --verbose [314ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:37.181Z] > git config --get commit.template [322ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:37.646Z] > git status -z -uall [459ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:37.722Z] > git check-ignore -v -z --stdin [326ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:37.944Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Downloads\grabbitapp-v1.0.9\lib\main.dart [375ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:38.019Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [354ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:38.029Z] > git show --textconv :lib/main.dart [484ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:38.211Z] > git cat-file -s 5d6402f0276f3fd5b022360f84c102449513b154 [263ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:38.283Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [260ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:38.614Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Downloads\grabbitapp-v1.0.9\lib\main.dart [385ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:38.654Z] > git remote --verbose [364ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:38.655Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [368ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:38.977Z] > git config --get commit.template [311ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:38.991Z] > git cat-file -s 5d6402f0276f3fd5b022360f84c102449513b154 [373ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:39.126Z] > git status -z -uall [137ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:39.174Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [45ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:39.221Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [44ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:39.281Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [57ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:39.282Z] > git remote --verbose [55ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:38:39.366Z] > git config --get commit.template [73ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:40:45.853Z] > git check-ignore -v -z --stdin [108ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:40:48.737Z] > git check-ignore -v -z --stdin [87ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:40:51.641Z] > git branch [79ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:40:51.763Z] > git rm --cached -r -- . [118ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:40:51.763Z] error: the following file has staged content different from both the
    file and the HEAD:
        .dhiwise/config
    (use -f to force removal)
    [2022-07-09T08:41:39.111Z] > git fetch [112ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:41:39.188Z] > git status -z -uall [69ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:41:39.236Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [43ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:41:39.308Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [69ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:41:39.356Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [46ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:41:39.359Z] > git remote --verbose [44ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:41:39.406Z] > git config --get commit.template [38ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:41:40.401Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Downloads\grabbitapp-v1.0.9\lib\main.dart [39ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:41:40.443Z] > git cat-file -s 5d6402f0276f3fd5b022360f84c102449513b154 [39ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:41:40.516Z] > git show --textconv :lib/main.dart [45ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:07.781Z] > git status -z -uall [84ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:07.896Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [111ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:07.939Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Downloads\grabbitapp-v1.0.9\lib\main.dart [106ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:07.981Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [81ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:08.028Z] > git cat-file -s 5d6402f0276f3fd5b022360f84c102449513b154 [85ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:08.075Z] > git remote --verbose [86ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:08.082Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [96ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:08.178Z] > git config --get commit.template [84ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:08.329Z] > git show --textconv :lib/main.dart [222ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:09.080Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Downloads\grabbitapp-v1.0.9\lib\main.dart [86ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:09.116Z] > git cat-file -s 5d6402f0276f3fd5b022360f84c102449513b154 [33ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:42:09.182Z] > git show --textconv :lib/main.dart [40ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:39.607Z] > git fetch [101ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:39.688Z] > git status -z -uall [69ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:39.732Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [35ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:39.774Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [38ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:39.842Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [61ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:39.843Z] > git remote --verbose [58ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:39.914Z] > git config --get commit.template [40ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:40.845Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Downloads\grabbitapp-v1.0.9\lib\main.dart [42ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:40.894Z] > git cat-file -s 5d6402f0276f3fd5b022360f84c102449513b154 [46ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:40.950Z] > git show --textconv :lib/main.dart [43ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:46.970Z] > git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet [964ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:46.970Z] Error: Bad status code: 500
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (c:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\git-editor-main.js:1:470)
        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
        at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:623:27)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
        at Socket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:487:22)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
        at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
        at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
        at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    error: There was a problem with the editor '"c:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\git-editor.sh"'.
    Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
    [2022-07-09T08:44:47.017Z] > git config --get-all user.name [41ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:44:47.059Z] > git config --get-all user.email [39ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.145Z] > git fetch [139ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.220Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Downloads\grabbitapp-v1.0.9\lib\main.dart [76ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.321Z] > git cat-file -s 5d6402f0276f3fd5b022360f84c102449513b154 [97ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.408Z] > git status -z -uall [242ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.463Z] > git show --textconv :lib/main.dart [106ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.496Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [82ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.545Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [45ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.613Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [64ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.617Z] > git remote --verbose [64ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:45.709Z] > git config --get commit.template [76ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:46.506Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Downloads\grabbitapp-v1.0.9\lib\main.dart [54ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:46.546Z] > git cat-file -s 5d6402f0276f3fd5b022360f84c102449513b154 [36ms]
    [2022-07-09T08:48:46.618Z] > git show --textconv :lib/main.dart [40ms]
```

This is shown if the command output is clicked

[image]

Comment: What happens if you press "Show Command Output"?

Comment: Its in image 2 above, ty

Comment: The commit message is missing "Please supply the message using either -m or -F option". Hopefully I typed it correctly from the image... :-(

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 15):

Go to VSCode's settings and search for `git: use editor as commit input`.

An option with tick box will appear:

[image]

If that option is on just turn it off by unticking it.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't leave blank the message before you commit the changes :D

[image: message box]

Comment: Gosh! It was asking for comment till date. Suddenly it started committing without asking for comment and ending up giving error! Wth! Many thanks for this hint saved my efforts :) Cheers!